# Conversion error for RequestParameter with a List of byte array

Tags: spring-mvc

I have the following REST resource and can't find a way to call it.

```
public ResponseEntity<Foo> getAll(final Optional<List<byte[]>> ids )
```

What i did try is this:

```
final List<ByteBuffer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
 ids.add( ByteBuffer.wrap( "ids".getBytes()) );


 getWebTestClient().get().uri( uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
             .path("path" )
             .queryParam( "ids", "{ids}" )
             .build( ids ) )
```

Error is:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@jakarta.validation.Valid @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam byte] for value [[java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=696 cap=696]]]
```

Second try

```
final List<byte[]> ids = new ArrayList<>();
ids.add( "ids".getBytes() );

 getWebTestClient().get().uri( uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
             .path("path" )
             .queryParam( "ids", "{ids}" )
             .build( ids ) )
```

Error is:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@jakarta.validation.Valid @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam byte] for value [[[B@7dd1b3c0]]
```

Anyone have an idea how I can solve this?